# Analytical solution to the first PCA direction

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, svd

It is known that the first PCA direction for a dataset of $n$ points is the unit vector with max variance after projecting the points onto this vector. I wonder whether there are some analytical solutions to compute this vector, instead of using the power method and the like? Or are there some fast algorithms to compute the vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that an analytic solution does not exist for data of 5 or more dimensions and does exist for data with less than 5 dimensions.

**Proof for data with 5 dimensions or more**

Given $\lambda = (\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_5)$, we can find an arbitrary 5x5 symmetric matrix $P_{\lambda}$ with eigenvalues $\lambda$, and characteristic polynomial :

$p(t) = a \cdot (t - \lambda_1)(t - \lambda_2)(t - \lambda_3)(t - \lambda_4)(t - \lambda_5)$

Saying that we can find an analytical solution for the first principal component of data with co-variance matrix $P_{\lambda}$, implies that we can analytically find a root of $p(t) = 0$. But it is known that there is no analytical solution for the roots of 5th (or higher) degree polynomials.

**For data with less than 5 dimensions**

Let's say you have 4-dimensional data with 4x4 covariance matrix. There is a (very complicated) formula for the roots of 4th degree polynomials. You can analytically compute all the roots of the characteristic polynomial $\lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2 \ge \lambda_3 \ge \lambda_4$, find the corresponding eigenvector by solving the 4x4 linear system $(A - \lambda_1 I)v = 0$, and normalize the vector $v$. Here you go - your first principal component.